# Kill a Word.Basic application process without killing Word.Application main process

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a script to assist users to take screenshots in a loop and save them to a word document.

My code is working, but the problem I'm facing is that for each screenshot I'm creating a `WINWORD.EXE` process and the process is not being killed, so if I run my script several times or take many screenshots in a single run, I will end up with a massive amount of processes that I'd have to manually kill.

This is my script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strPath : strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
Dim strMainPath : strMainPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

' Cleaning
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

Dim objWord : Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
objWord.Documents.Open strMainPath & "\template\template.doc"

Const wdStory = 6
Const wdMove = 0

Dim objSelection : Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.EndKey wdStory, wdMove

Dim execFlag : execFlag = True

Do While execFlag = True

    Dim strPrint : strPrint = InputBox("Enter screenshot name","Screenshot Name", "")
    With objSelection 
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = "10"
        .TypeText strPrint
    End With

    objSelection.TypeParagraph()

    WScript.Sleep 5000

    'Taking Screenshot using word object
    With CreateObject("Word.Basic")    'This is the point where I create the processes that I'm unable to kill
        .SendKeys "{prtsc}"    
    End With

    ' Paste in the screen shot
    objWord.Selection.Paste

    Dim intAnswer : intAnswer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo, "Printscreen")

    If intAnswer = vbNo Then execFlag = False

    objSelection.EndKey wdStory, wdMove
    objSelection.TypeParagraph()

Loop

Dim strFileName : strFileName = ""
Do 
    strFileName = InputBox("Provide the file name","File Name", "")
Loop While strFileName = ""

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strMainPath & "\" & strFileName & ".doc"
objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
objword.Quit
Set objword = Nothing

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open strMainPath & "\" & strFileName & ".doc"
Set objWord = Nothing
```

These are the processes I'm referring to. I cannot simply kill all processes because one of them actually refers to my template, which is a Word document where I'm storing my screenshots. Any tips on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Where you are taking your screen shot is creating excess processes. Each time you run through the loop, you create a new process. At the top of your code, type `Dim objBasic : Set objBasic = CreateObject("Word.Basic")`, then replace your `With` block with `objBasic.SendKeys "{prtsc}"`. Immediately after before the end of the loop, type `Set objBasic = Nothing`. This should prevent multiple processes from occurring.

Comment: @Lou Thank you very much. That solved my issue. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent excess processes from occurring, your code should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strPath : strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
Dim strMainPath : strMainPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
Dim objBasic : Set objBasic = CreateObject("Word.Basic") 

' Cleaning
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

Dim objWord : Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
objWord.Documents.Open strMainPath & "\template\template.doc"

Const wdStory = 6
Const wdMove = 0

Dim objSelection : Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.EndKey wdStory, wdMove

Dim execFlag : execFlag = True

Do While execFlag = True

    Dim strPrint : strPrint = InputBox("Enter screenshot name","Screenshot Name", "")
    With objSelection 
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = "10"
        .TypeText strPrint
    End With

    objSelection.TypeParagraph()

    WScript.Sleep 5000

    'Taking Screenshot using word object
    objBasic.SendKeys "{prtsc}"

    ' Paste in the screen shot
    objWord.Selection.Paste

    Dim intAnswer : intAnswer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo, "Printscreen")

    If intAnswer = vbNo Then execFlag = False

    objSelection.EndKey wdStory, wdMove
    objSelection.TypeParagraph()
    Set objBasic = Nothing

Loop

Dim strFileName : strFileName = ""
Do 
    strFileName = InputBox("Provide the file name","File Name", "")
Loop While strFileName = ""

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strMainPath & "\" & strFileName & ".doc"
objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
objword.Quit
Set objword = Nothing

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open strMainPath & "\" & strFileName & ".doc"
Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: fyi: you can use `WordBasic` from `Word.Application` to avoid creating the separate instance --> `objWord.WordBasic.SendKeys "{prtsc}"`